# Can't boot after upgrading to 15.04

Tags: boot, swap, 15.04

I'm an amateur Linux user, so excuse my ignorance.

After upgrading to 15.04, the screen hangs on the Ubuntu loading image and then finally goes to a black screen with the following:

```
[ 1.595012] ACPI PCC probe failed.
Starting version 219.
Welcome to emergency mode
...
```

If I press on the down arrow during the Ubuntu loading image screen I get a long list of actions with an `[OK]` on the left but one with a `[FAILED]`.  The `[FAILED]` one says this:

```
Failed to activate swap Swap Partition.
See "systemctl status dev-sda7.swap" for details.
```

At at the bottom of the black screen it says:

```
A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2 duuid-ec5ce .... [string of letters and numbers].device
```

The above sentence has a timer after it which counts to 1 min 30 seconds and then goes to the screen above which starts with

```
[1.595012]...
```

I have all my pictures and work stored on this laptop so I need to find a way to boot up!

**edit 26.05.2015**
Unfortunately none of the proposed solutions have worked. The IT support company that supports the business I work for got to the point of accessing the data but the home folder is encrypted and I don't have the key (which, sillily, is saved on my desktop). Data recovery specialists I called said they can't help, so it looks like I'll be losing the last few months of data on my laptop including photos of my 5 month old girl.

Comment: hi dan what is the system your running i.e. what type of processor , how much memory , and what kind of graphics cards is fitted ? is it a laptop or a desktop.

Comment: Hi Daron. Laptop XPS 13, Intel Core  i5-3317U CPU@1.70GHz, 4GB RAM, Intel HD graphics 4000.  Duel boot with Win 8.  THe issue seems similar to this one:   https://askubuntu.com/questions/614463/swap-doesnt-seem-to-mount-after-update/614470#614470

Comment: which graphics card is it dan is it nvidia or onboard intel

Comment: H Daron, it's an onboard Intel.

Comment: ok  from what i can see it is struggling to find the swap partition and also the hard drive information. Did you as part of the install use the lvm encryption ? when selecting what hard drive space. i would hazard a guess that you did. With this in mind i feel the best thing to do would be choose reinstall of 15 .04 burt not encrypting the hard disk space with lvm

Comment: please let me know if you have information stored on the laptop and we can discuss ways to get that information off before having to do a reinstall but given the error as in not finding the hard drive that could prove to be quite tricky.

Comment: Hi Daron.  Thanks.  yes, I did encrypt the home folder.  How can I reinstall 15.04?  If you're able to give basic instructions would be really appreciated.  Right now I can only get to the "Welcome to emergency mode" screen.

Comment: Hi Daron, I do have information stored on the laptop.

Comment: Unfortunately none of the proposed solutions have worked. The IT support company that supports the business I work for got to the point of accessing the data but the home folder is encrypted and I don't have the key (which, sillily, is saved on my desktop). Data recovery specialists I called said they can't help. So it looks like I'll be loosing the last few months of data on my laptop including photos of my 5 month old girl. This is a major disappointment and an incredible failure of Ubuntu. Updates should not be released if they cause major failures like this

Comment: this link worked for me ,I hope it works for you too :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/652599/ubuntu-wont-start-emergency-mode

Comment: If you have "windows" on your machine : I had similar problem too and this link worked for me ,I hope it works for you too:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/652599/ubuntu-wont-start-emergency-mode

Answer (score 1):

I had some similar errors with my system, and I found that it was an error with some `fstab` entries (external drives that were no longer physically connected). I just commented them out and the system booted as usual.