# Ubuntu 16.04 can't boot to desktop after creating windows-shared NTFS partition

Tags: boot, lts

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I followed [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35807/how-to-harmonize-your-dual-boot-setup-for-windows-and-ubuntu/) guide to have a shared partition with Windows 10. I put my Win10 Downloads and Documents folder on the partition.

When i had turned off the computer a couple of times (and probably entered windows) i could no longer boot to ubuntu. I chose ubuntu in Grub (regular ubuntu preinstalled grub) but came to the full screen terminal saying it's in emergency mode.

What to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu won't start, emergency mode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/652599/ubuntu-wont-start-emergency-mode)

Comment: Yes, that question "buntu won't start..." is very similar, but maybe the title is too bad because i didn't find it when googling to solve the problem.

Comment: You should try to disable 'secure boot' in BIOS, for me it worked and also make sure in your windows 'fast boot' is off and your partitions has nothing to do with it.I have 2 NTFS partitions in windows 10 and they works fine with Ubuntu.

Comment: @ratcoder, yes fast boot in Win10  was the problem, but I allready answered my question below:)

Comment: @JonatanÖström then I suppose you should change your title because as I already said the problem has nothing to do with NTFS partition.

Comment: @ratcoder Well i think it could. If it was Ext file system then windows couldn't read it, so it wouldn't be an issue. If it was FAT it would just be like a USB-drive. With NTFS the problem uccured. On the other hand, it might be becaus I put my Downloads folder on this partition that Windows locked it down for "fast boot". I dont know.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that one has to uncheck "fast startup" in Windows 8/10 `control panel` > `power options` > `shange what the power buttons do` (bottom of page. Might have to ckick "turn on disabled options.. something" on the top of the page if the fast option is greyed out). This was not mentioned in the guide.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  One has to turn fastboot ON or OFF?

Comment: Sorry, i rewrote it more clearly now!